# Android background location updates?

Tags: android, location

I already know how to get the user's current location using:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10, 500, locationListener)
```

But what are the usual steps required when running location updates in the background on Android??

Must I keep the entire application running in the background with the GPS on??

I basically want to send the user's latitude longitude back to our servers periodically, if not on a timer, then maybe when there has been a movement of more than 25m for example.

I also don't want to kill the battery, which constant GPS use is notorious for.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you create a Class which extends [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html), this service will run in the background. [This is an example, which will store the GPS data in a SQLite database](http://code.google.com/p/gpslogger/source/browse/trunk/GPSLogger/src/com/prom2m/android/gpslogger/service/GPSLoggerService.java). This might point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Can you use the cellular network for pinging user's geographical data in certain intervals. Once you figure that the position has changed by a certain variable, you can then activate the GPS and get exact coordinates to send back to your server. Remember to stop receiving location updates once you are done (for obvious battery-draining reasons.)

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
```

Cellular network is accurate to 50m so that might serve your need for the recurring ping- with some compromise between accuracy and battery life.

Answer (score 1):

This service I have used to update my location in background to my localhost server

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import com.google.android.gcm.GCMRegistrar;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LocationService extends Service{

@Override
public void onCreate() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate();
final LocationManager mlocmag = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
final LocationListener mlocList = new MyLocationList();
final Location loc = mlocmag.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
   // This method is used to get updated location. 
mlocmag.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocList);
LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
Location mostRecentLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
UpdateWithNewLocation(mostRecentLocation); 


}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onDestroy();
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onStart(intent, startId);
}
 private void UpdateWithNewLocation(final Location loc) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if(loc!= null)
    {
    final double lat =loc.getLatitude(); // Updated lat
    final double Long = loc.getLongitude(); // Updated long
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    String Latitude=String.valueOf(lat);
    String Longitude=String.valueOf(Long);
    // define the parameter
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lat",Latitude));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("lang", Longitude));
    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regId", regId));
    String response = null;

    // call executeHttpPost method passing necessary parameters 
    try {
    response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost(
   "http://192.168.0.144/location.php", // your ip address if using localhost server

 postParameters);
    String result=response.toString();
   // Toast.makeText(this, result ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }catch (Exception e) {
         Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     
        }
    }

    else 
    {
         String latLongStr = "No lat and longitude found";
         Toast.makeText(this, "Your location is "+latLongStr ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}
 public class MyLocationList implements LocationListener
 {

 public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     UpdateWithNewLocation(arg0);
 }

 public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS Disable ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 }


}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's kind of hard to do because if you dont request the position periodically you can't find out if the phone moved, and it can move fast as a car or slow as a person so I figured out a possibility:

I don't know exactly how acelerometer works on android and what is it's precision (sure it must be device dependent) but it's possible to use those sensors to indirectly evaluate approximate traveled distance.

**[EDIT]**

Note that using acelerometer will use some power and you will need it running constantly, so using GPS with a smaller "sampling rate" can be more efficient and, with more precision for sure.

Comment: GPS may not be more accurate at all times, especially in crowded city with skyscrapers all around. In such case, cellular network provides more accurate information.